# How to change background color of stack panel when selected in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I have to change the background color of StackPanel (present in `DataGrid`) when it is selected or focused.

Below is the my `XAML`:

```
<DataGrid Background="#DCE1E7" SelectedItem="{Binding Row, Mode=TwoWay}"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" HeadersVisibility="None"  GridLinesVisibility="None" HorizontalAlignment="Left" BorderThickness="0" Name="dtlCuisine" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderBrush="#DCE1E7" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#DCE1E7" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#DCE1E7"   ColumnWidth="130" SelectionChanged="dtlCuisine_SelectionChanged" CellEditEnding="dtlCuisine_CellEditEnding">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="Template13">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Name="stkpnlCuisines" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="#DCE1E7" Margin="-1,-1,-1,-1" MouseDown="stkpnlCuisines_MouseDown_1">
                        <Label Content="{Binding CuisineName}" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="lblCuisineName" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="14" />
                        <StackPanel.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsFocused}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </StackPanel.Style>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="-1,-1,-1,-1">
                        <TextBox Name="txtCuisineCategory" AcceptsReturn="True" Text="{Binding CuisineName}" LostFocus="txtCuisineCategory_LostFocus" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

What is the best way to change the `Background` color of `StackPanel`.

Comment: Have you tried the Style Triggers (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.triggers.aspx)

Comment: Yes I have tried trigger but not working

Comment: <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

Answer (score 1):

Use the IsSelected trigger on the DataGridCell. If you wan't to completely change the selected colors accross all elements, then you can use the following code in your application resources.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#3271B5" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="AliceBlue" />
```

Comment: Thanks. I have used DataGridCell trigger now its working fine